# mongodb Documents property

Tags: mongodb, select, findall

I am using mongodb 2.0.5 version.
Trying to connect mongodb from c#.
Inserting data to monogdb is working fine.

but i want to retrieve data from mongodb and display to user.
Problem is Document property is not coming in intellisense.
Below is my code:

```
namespace mongoTest
{
    public class dbsDani
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string Emp_name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            #region connectionTried

            MongoServer server;
            String con = "mongodb://192.168.71.241/?safe=true";
            server = MongoServer.Create(con);
            server.Connect();
            if (server.State == MongoServerState.Connected)
            {
                //server.Connect();
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
                //MongoCredentials credentials = new MongoCredentials("danny", "levay");
                var dbseName = server.GetDatabase("danny");
                var collectionName = dbseName.GetCollection<dbsDani>("dani");
                var emp = new dbsDani { Emp_name = "Jack" };
                collectionName.Insert(emp);
                var id = emp.Id;

    var display = collectionName.FindAll().documents(); //FindAll().Documents is not coming
                foreach (var document in display)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(document["Emp_name"]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not coming in intellisense because it doesn't exist.  FindAll() returns a MonogCursor<dbsDani> of which you can iterate over.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do, but I changed your problem line to:

```
       var display = collectionName.FindAll();
```

and I can now iterate over documents via

```
       foreach (var document in display)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(document.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(document.Emp_name);
        }
```

I got back:

```
4ff0e528594bc07645d8bb6b
Jack
```